# C# работа с base64 и сохранение pdf файла

Tags: c#, .net, строки, pdf

есть код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String line=string.Empty;
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Serik\Desktop\pdf_test\"+i+".txt"))
            {
                line =line+ sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(line);
            FileStream stream =
            new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Serik\Desktop\pdf_test\file.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
            System.IO.BinaryWriter writer =
                new BinaryWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            writer.Close();
```

который с строки base64 делает pdf файл. Но есть предположение что ели string в котором хранится base64 у меня будет слишком длинный(большие pdf файлы), то программа не сработает (Так как у стринга есть допустимая длинна ) Как c этим бороться? что можно кроме string использовать?

Comment: Думал использовать StringBuilder но Convert.FromBase64String принемает только string

Comment: А какая у вас проблема? Файл формируется? Выложите ошибку приложения, или сообщите что битый файл pdf выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У строк нет ограничений, в которые вы могли бы упереться с pdf файлами.
Больше вероятность получить `OutOfMemory` при достижении 2гб размера для 32битных приложений.

По информации с enSO - 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468/3768545